# UX for letting user drag a Google map marker and enter form fields

Tags: forms, google-maps, maps, usability

I want to allow the user to specify the location of something by dragging a marker onto the map.  And I also want to let them enter some information about that spot.

The problem is that this makes a very complex form.  Can this be done in one step?  Or do I have to make them choose location first, and then in a second form take the form-field input?

How would you guys go about doing this?  Are there any good tutorials for this sort of thing out there?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean in one step?I implemented this by adding a floating form in the side of a map and adding two hidden(or not?) fields that populated with the coords of the draggable marker.I really don't see any other way except maybe if you embed the form in the info window of the draggable marker

Cheers